# How to run GUI application from linux container in Window using Docker?

Tags: window, docker, boot2docker, docker-compose

I have a QT based GUI application which i compiled in docker (centos image). I am able to launch GUI application from inside Centos image in my Linux machine(OpenSUSE 13.2)
Following instruction from this blog 
"http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker"

Same thing i want to do via window.I installed window docker . I loaded the desired centos images having my GUI application and and through terminal trying to launch GUI by using  container . It gives Error saying" gui: cannot connect to X server"

Any idea or solution .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a similar discussion on [docker issue 8710](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8710), but for MacOS:

> A somewhat crude way to do this:
>
> Start `socat` to expose local `xquartz` socket on a TCP port

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\"
```

(Note: for Windows, you would need at least:

- an [X11 server like Xming](https://rcc.its.psu.edu/user_guides/remote_display/xming/)
- to check if [`socat` is available for Windows](http://blog.gentilkiwi.com/programmes/socat)
  )

> Pass the display to container (assuming virtualbox host is available on 192.168.59.3):

```
 docker run -e DISPLAY=192.168.59.3:0 jess/geary
```

> (This is insecure on public networks, add `bind`, `su` and `range` options to socat to limit access.)

Answer (score 2):

I started vncserver and then can see my application with vncviewer .

Answer (score 0):

This solution based on a blog article from [Robin Kretzschmar](https://dev.to/darksmile92/run-gui-app-in-linux-docker-container-on-windows-host-4kde). I tested it with the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:22.10
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y kate
CMD kate
```

The container is build with

```
docker build . -t test/kate
```

On your Windows Host you need to install a x-server, I used VcSrv. After you started VcSrv, you can run

```
docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0.0 test/kate
```

and an instance of kate is shown